# How to communicate Different VLANs in Different Switches

Tags: cisco, switch, router, vlan

I have 3 switches, 2 switches connected to 1 main switch.
I have VLAN6, VLAN7, VLAN8 and VLAN9.

- VLAN6 has VLAN6-1 end device.
- VLAN7 has VLAN7-1 end device.
- VLAN8 has VLAN8-1 and VLAN8-2 end devices.
- VLAN9 has VLAN9-1 and VLAN9-2 end devices.

After some configurations,

- VLAN8-1 and VLAN8-2 can communicate right now.
- VLAN9-1 and VLAN9-2 can communicate right now.
- VLAN6-1 and VLAN7-1 can't communicate any devices.

I need to communicate VLAN8 and VLAN9. So, VLAN8-1 and VLAN8-2 have to communicate with VLAN9-1 and VLAN9-2. I tried to change switch modes switch1 and switch2 to trunk mode(with VLAN1,VLAN8,VLAN9) but it didn't work. It's working only when I change switches mode to access mode.

[image: Config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All traffic between your VLANs must flow through the router.  Ports connected to the PCs should be access ports. Configure the connections between your switches as trunks as well as the link to the router.  Configure sub-interfaces on the router for each VLAN.

Comment: Thank you, I used encapsulation dot1q for handle.

Answer (score 0):

All the vlan gateway should connect to router interface .use intervlan concept on router by creating sub -interfaces. By intervlan concept different vlan will communicate. And traffic will reach to router . If you can to restrict traffic between vlan as per your requirement, then use access-list in router ...

Answer (score 0):

Ports conntected between switch and router should be trunk

Switch to switch port should be trunk as well

Switch to PC's should be access ports